# Getting exception while running CustomDatePicker

Tags: android, exception

I had given a task to integrate `custom datetimepicker`. I googled and found one plugin which I am trying to integrate into my codebase.
Can anyone help me on below mentioned issue?
After integrating code for datetime picker, on running an app its giving exception as mentioned below.

```
file line #63: **Error inflating class com.syntempo.craft.framework.common.datetimepicker.CustomDatePicker**
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2320)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2380)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1285)
                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
                             Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class com.syntempo.craft.framework.common.datetimepicker.CustomDatePicker
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.createCustomViewInternal(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:211)
                                at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.access$000(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:20)
                                at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:302)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:177)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                at com.syntempo.craft.activity.tx.status.StatusActivityFragment.onCreateView(StatusActivityFragment.java:151)
                                at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1045)
                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1147)
                                at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2116)
                                at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5367)
                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:303)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:177)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                at com.syntempo.craft.activity.tx.status.StatusActivity.onCreate(StatusActivity.java:20)
                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreat
```

Comment: Post your xml where you have included this custom datepicker

Comment: You have not provided the correct path for CustomDatePicker in your xml file